# How to edit this foreach loop that array with the same key gets combined?

Tags: php, loops

My problem is that the foreach loop creates every time a new array. I want that it is all in a array and elements with the same key should get combined:

```php
foreach ($lines as $line) {
   if (true) {
        $lineName = strtok($line, " "); // takes the first word
        $lineNameCleaned = substr($lineName, strpos($lineName, '@') + 1); // deletes all @ before a lineName
   }

   $res = [$lineNameCleaned => $line,];
}
```

the `$res` Array creates every time a new array but I want that the result is like this:

```
array = [
   'lineName1' => [ 
           'value 1',
           'value 2',
         ],
    'lineName2' => [
            'value3',
         ],
   ];
```

So that values with the same key (lineName) are in the same array.

Comment: Where does `value1` and `value2` come from?

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Obviously, the given code does not reuse anything from prior loops

Comment: @Qirel that is the value from $line

Comment: But `$line` is a string - and the values you added as your expected result is an array. So which is it?

Comment: Probably `$res[$lineNameCleaned][] = $line;` (or some combination of variables in this style)